# Ajax/PHP form not validating

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, webforms

I'm trying to create a contact form that validates and submits without actually refreshing the page, or disrupting the user experience.

I've been using a contact form from [www.w3bees.com](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/submit-form-without-page-refresh-with.html) so far and I've implimented the code, but it doesn't actually validate, it just keeps submitting regardless and I cannot figure out why, so I thought it was time to ask for help.

Here is the exact php code that I am using:

```
<?php


# request sent using HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){
if (isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['subject']) AND     isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $to = 'hi@email.com';

    $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sent = email($to, $email, $name, $subject, $message);
    if ($sent) {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    } else {
        echo 'Message couldn\'t sent!';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'All Fields are required';
}
return;
}

/**
 * email function
 *
 * @return bool | void
 **/
function email($to, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message){
$header = array();
$header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$header[] = "From: {$from_name}<{$from_mail}>";
/* Set message content type HTML*/
$header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
if( mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true; 
}

?>
```

Here is the actual contact form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="weeform" role="search" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"   placeholder="Name">

          <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

          <label class="sr-only" for="subject">Subject</label>
          <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Message subject">

          <label class="sr-only" for="Message">Message/Query</label>
          <textarea type="text" id="Message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type message/query here."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value"submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('#weeform'); // contact form
var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button
var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

// form submit event
form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
    // sending ajax request through jQuery
    $.ajax({
        url: '', // form action url
        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
        data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
        beforeSend: function() {
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
});
});
```

It's a lot to look through, but I'm stumped and I've spent more time than I can afford looking at it, so I thought it best to seek advice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have jquery library stuff loaded!!?

Comment: Yes, I have the jQuery library loaded.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in chrome to test that the eventhandler is being bound?

Comment: Have you revised the process in the Console?

Comment: Also worth noting that success and error are to be deprecated, you should use done and fail instead going forwards. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to diagnose a problem, however it sounds to me that you need to add evt.preventDefault(); at the top of your onsubmit handler

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better call the actual PHP contact file in your `url` of the submit event function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php', //actual mail processor file
```

Comment: It's a single page website at present. The php is at the top of the document and the contact form is located further down, towards the bottom.

Do you think it would be better to create the contact form as an additional file (contact.php) and call it in as you say?

Thanks for commenting BTW :D

Comment: As it is on one page the ajax request will return a response containing the html of the entire current page.  It would definitely be better to separate it out to a page which just generates the html you would like to inject

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I tried what you recommended, but all it does is call in another contact form below the existing form. I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.